# How to determine first and last call of module scoped fixture within session?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a module scoped fixture that requires to know if it is called for the first or for the last time within a session, is there a way to get this information within fixture?

This is required for managing lifecycle of a shared resource that depends on module scoped options which basically should look like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', autouse=True)
def module_runner():

    if not session_start and resource_reload_condition:
        shared_resource.dispatch()

    shared_resource.set_module_level_options()

    if resource_reload_condition:
        shared_resource.provision()

    yield

    if resource_reload_condition:
        shared_resource.dispatch()

    shared_resource.rollback_module_level_options()

    if not session_end and resource_reload_condition:
        shared_resource.provision()
```

Comment: AFAIK fixtures are called only once depending on scope. So once for module, once for class, once for function and once for session. Your fixture should only be called once per module.

Comment: This page helped me a bit more to understand them: http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-fixtures-nuts-bolts/ Also this documentation page explains pretty well how to parametrize them for repeated use: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: @BoboDarph I'm aware that they are called only once depending on a scope, but this is bit different from what I'm asking. For example, I'm executing tests from 5 modules, so module scoped fixture will be called 5 times and I want to know when it is called for the first time and for the fifth time within fixture itself to provision and dispatch resource correctly.

Comment: That will only happen if you parametrize them. That is what the second link is for. If you parametrize it with a list of values, you could always use the param value or it's position in the list for example (or other ordered objects). https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures

Comment: @BoboDarph I don't see how parametrization can help here. I can have 100 or 1000 modules and I definitely don't want to have the same amount of params, also execution order is not guaranteed and even it is possible to run tests in predefined order it is not a good idea to do so.